# How to fix WTForm Validation Error ('Not a valid decimal value') on DecimalField with '%' on the Front End?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

### Problem/Question

I want to show '%' sign on the WTForm DecimalField for users but I keep getting the following error when adding new data even with the manual changes I tried on 'discount.data' (see below):

```
{
    "addErr": {
        "discount": [
            "Not a valid decimal value"
        ]
    },
    "addStatus": "FAIL"
}
```

How can I make sure the '%' gets removed properly and the correct value passed on to the WTForm validation and actually pass the validation?

### Requirements

```
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
WTForms==2.3.3
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
psycopg2==2.8.6
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.36.7
postgres 13
```

### SQLAlchemy Model

```
class CustomerDiscount(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblCustomerDiscount"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('customer_id', 'subProduct_id',
                                       'description', 'discount', 'dateEffStart', name='customerDiscount_uc'),
                    {'schema': 'management'})
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(
        'management.tblCustomer.id'), nullable=False)
    subProduct_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(
        'management.tblSubProduct.id'), nullable=False)
    discount = Column(DECIMAL(5,4), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    dateEffStart = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    dateEffEnd = Column(DateTime)
    isactive = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=1)
    customer = relationship(
        'Customer', foreign_keys=[customer_id])
    subProduct = relationship(
        'SubProduct', foreign_keys=[subProduct_id])
```

### Route

```
@customerdiscounts.route("/customerdiscounts/add", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def add_customerdiscount():
    addX = FormCustomerDiscountAdd(request.form)
    addX.customer_id.data = request.form['customer_id']
    addX.subProduct_id.data = request.form['subProduct_id']
    addX.discount.data = float(str(request.form['discount']).replace('%', ''))/100
    addX.dateEffStart.data = datetime.strptime(
        request.form['dateEffStart'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    if addX.validate_on_submit():
        x = CustomerDiscount()
        x.customer_id = addX.customer_id.data
        x.subProduct_id = addX.subProduct_id.data
        x.description = addX.description.data
        x.discount = addX.discount.data
        x.dateEffStart = addX.dateEffStart.data
        x.dateEffEnd = addX.dateEffEnd.data
        x.isactive = True
        syncNext('management', 'CustomerDiscount', 'id') #this is a custom function that ensures the correct value for 'id'
        print(f'x.discount: {x.discount}')
        sess.add(x)
        sess.commit()
        return jsonify(addStatus='OK', addDesc=x.description)
    else:
        return jsonify(addStatus='FAIL', addErr=addX.errors)
```

### Variations to the 'discount.data' that I have tried

Manually set/overwriten the following properties on the codes shown on the route above:

```
addX.discount.data = 0.0123 #other variation include '0.0123', '0.12' i.e. string format

addX.discount.raw_data = addX.discount.data #other variation include '0.0123', '0.12', ['0.0123']
```

Note that the single quotes above were not for emphasis but rather to denote string.

### WTForm

I've purposely removed most validations in my attempt to isolate the problem

```
class FormCustomerDiscountAdd(FormCustomerDiscount):
    customer_id = SelectField('Customer',
                            choices=FormCustomerDiscount.customers)
    subProduct_id = SelectField('SubProduct',
                                choices=FormCustomerDiscount.subproducts)
    description = StringField(u'Discount Description', render_kw={
        "placeholder": "Describe motivation for discount"})
    discount = DecimalField('Discount in %', render_kw={'id': 'discount_add'}, places=4, rounding=None)
    dateEffStart = DateField('Effective Start Date')
    dateEffEnd = DateField('Effective End Date', validators=[
                            validators.Optional()] )
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

below shows the discount with full validation:

```
discount = DecimalField('Discount in %', render_kw={'id': 'discount_add'}, places=4, rounding=None, validators=[validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=100), valAdd])
```

The 'valAdd' is a custom validator that queries DB for entries which may exist already.

### JS - To have '%' shown on the Decimal Field

The code below adds the character '%' on the field when the value changes and also make sure that the entered value is between 0 and 100 inclusive.

Note that the front end is supposed to accept values from 0 to 100 including decimals but the actual data gets converted to values between 0 and 1 with 5 digit precision and 4 decimals (e.g. 1.23% on the front end and 0.0123 on postgres)

```
$(function(){
    percentField('#discount_add');
});

function percentField(tgtFld){
    let minNumber = 0;
    let maxNumber = 100;
    $(tgtFld).on("change", function() {
        let inputVal = parseFloat($(this).val().replace('%', '')) || 0;
        if (minNumber > inputVal) {
            inputVal = minNumber;
        } else if (maxNumber < inputVal) {
            inputVal = maxNumber;
        }
        $(this).val(inputVal + '%');
        $(this).selectionStart = $(this).selectionEnd = $(this).val().length - 1;
    });
}
```

Note that i have tried the other method of using CSS/JS to wrap the input fiels in a div or span to include the '%' as others have suggested here on SO on a similar question but I find that it is not that readily applicable in my case since the validation errors gets inserted right after the input and it gets in between the input and the '%' sign.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by converting the request.form data to a dictionary, tweaking the value of the discount to fix the % and passing the dictionary to the the WTForm form class as data and not object. I noticed that there are at least three data properties which WTForm uses. These are .data, .object_data, .raw_data. I am not sure which is being passed on the validation. To use the data argument on the form I also had to pass formdata=None and obj=None like so:

```
fdata = request.form.to_dict()
fdata['discount'] = float(str(request.form['discount']).replace('%', ''))/100
addX = FormCustomerDiscountAdd(formdata=None, obj=None, data=fdata)
```